# How do I join a parent table to two child tables without duplication?

Tags: postgresql, join, query

parent table

| id | city_name | zip_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new york city | 10001 |
| 2 | los angeles | 90001 |
| 3 | chicago | 60007 |

Customer, child table

| id | customer_name | city_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alice | 1 | 428 Hartford Lane |
| 2 | betty | 1 | 249 George Street |
| 3 | cath | 3 | 12112 S Front Ave |
| 4 | daph | 3 | 8619 S Wolcott Ave |

Restaurant, child table

| id | address | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 256 Roehampton St. | 1 |
| 2 | 920 Cherry Camp Road | 3 |
| 3 | 7609 Mckinley Ave | 2 |
| 4 | 5723 Morgan Ave | 2 |

When using the following query,

```sql
    select c.id, c.city_name, c.zip_code, r.id, r.address, r.city_id, cus.id, cus.customer_name, cus.city_id, cus.address 
    from restaurant r 
    left join city c 
        on r.city_id = c.id 
     right join customer cus 
        on c.id = cus.city_id where c.id = 1;
```

There will be a duplicate restaurant address entry. How do I ensure that the restaurants and customers are distinct?

| id | city_name | zip_code | id | address | city_id | id | customer_name | city_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new york city | 10001 | 1 | 256 Roehampton St. | 1 | 1 | alice | 1 | 428 Hartford Lane |
| 1 | new york city | 10001 | 1 | 256 Roehampton St. | 1 | 2 | betty | 1 | 249 George Street |

***Edit: To add some context, I would like to return a json object of a city which contains its fields as well as a list of customers and a list of restaurants belonging to that particular city.

Is it more efficient to make three separate queries to populate that object, i.e.

```
select * from city where id = 1;
select * from customer where city_id = 1;
select * from restaurant where city_id = 1;
```

or
perform one query with two joins, with the expected result as the following, where there are no duplicate restaurants or customers

| id | city_name | zip_code | id | address | city_id | id | customer_name | city_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new york city | 10001 | 1 | 256 Roehampton St. | 1 | 1 | alice | 1 | 428 Hartford Lane |
| 1 | new york city | 10001 |  |  |  | 2 | betty | 1 | 249 George Street |

Or can I just use a distinct keyword to remove duplicates?

Comment: How do you want the end results to look like, please provide an example?

Comment: If you join on a non-unique column, you can get multiple rows. You have two people who live in New York, how do you want them to be displayed?

Comment: @J.D.  have added additional info

Comment: @Charlieface  have added additional info

Comment: Well... you _could_ use arrays, but I'm far from saying that is a best practice. Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af8a3af76b5cde8d4cafb680cf09b6e1

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is denormalize your data into a **JSON** object. This is usually not a standard thing to do from a relational database, but PostgreSQL has a cool function that makes it possible called [`row_to_json()`](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql). You should be able to *distinctify* your **JSON** object using that function accordingly on top of your query's result set.

Comment: ohh interesting, did not know such a function existed. However, I am using golang's built in package to execute queries and create the corresponding objects and json results

Comment: As `jsonb` is recommended over `json`, the proper function would be `to_jsonb()` rather than `row_to_json()`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - use two queries.

Restaurants appear in a city.
Customers appear in a city.
I see no relationship between Restaurants and Customers, so there's no way to "remove the duplication" that you're seeing.

You have two different sets of data, here, so use two different queries to retrieve them.